# Nesting visitor:update_form within visitor:details

Tags: devdemon, zoo-visitor

Is there any reason why I shouldn't nest visitor:update_form within visitor:details? The reason I want to do this is because visitor:update_form doesn't seem to work with the native Relationships field (i.e. can't get details from it in the template) and I want to allow / disallow access based on whether a user is related to an entry. Nesting seems to work, but it would be good to know I'm following best practice.

```
{exp:visitor:details}
    {if '{client_event:url_title}' == '{segment_2}'}
        {exp:visitor:update_form preserve_checkboxes="no" return="{uri_string}"}
            ...allow access, updates etc.
        {/exp:visitor:update_form}
    {if:else}
        ...don't allow access
    {/if}
{/exp:visitor:details}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try your code with `embed`.

Create new template in your `template group` having proper name `.your_template_name`

Now, your main `template` having below code :-

```
{exp:visitor:details}
    {if '{client_event:url_title}' == '{segment_2}'}
        {embed="your_template_group/.your_template_name"}
    {if:else}
        ...don't allow access
    {/if}
{/exp:visitor:details}
```

And your `embed` having below code :-

```
{exp:visitor:update_form preserve_checkboxes="no" return="{uri_string}"}
    ...allow access, updates etc.
{/exp:visitor:update_form}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm saying the nesting works, I just want to know if it's good practice. I know you shouldn't nest identical tags, but this isn't the case here. I'd rather not embed as I already have embeds (there would be embeds within embeds).